# "[Regeln, die Menschen] sich für das eigene Handeln geben"

Tags: translation

What does "sich für das eigene Handeln geben" mean?

For example, [here](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/buehne-und-konzert/ferdinand-von-schirachs-gott-in-duesseldorf-16949174-p2.html):

> Hinter dem unbedingten Individualismus des Urteils, so wird
> suggeriert, dürfen auch die Regeln nicht zurückbleiben, die
> Berufsstände oder auch einzelne Menschen, die mit dem Wunsch nach
> Sterbehilfe konfrontiert werden können, sich für das eigene Handeln
> geben sollten.

Comment: I suspect that if the OP had understood the sentence sufficiently to formulate the current heading, they would not have had to ask the question. I understand the edit, but I believe that it is misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is quite a sentence.

Let's shorten this step by step and mercilessly, to get to the core of the part “sich für das eigene Handeln geben”:

> Hinter dem unbedingten Individualismus des Urteils, so wird suggeriert, dürfen auch die Regeln nicht zurückbleiben, die Berufsstände oder auch einzelne Menschen, die mit dem Wunsch nach Sterbehilfe konfrontiert werden können, sich für das eigene Handeln geben sollten.

=> (leave out subclauses and attributes)

> Hinter dem Individualismus des Urteils dürfen auch die Regeln nicht zurückbleiben, die Berufsstände oder auch einzelne Menschen sich für das eigene Handeln geben sollten.

=> (leave out more clutter)

> Die Regeln dürfen nicht zurückbleiben, die Berufsstände sich für das eigene Handeln geben sollten.

=> (take out just the "die ..." subclause, make it a full sentence and replace the pronoun by the noun it represents)

> Berufsstände sollten sich Regeln (für das eigene Handeln) geben.

Which means:

> Professions should give themselves rules (for their own actions).
> Professions should make rules for themselves (for their actions).

Does that help? The full sentence really is a lot. The author Patrick Bahners is known for this kind of over-the-top intellectualism. He can really pull it off.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Intellectuals, eh?